# Delete entire tag?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to figure this one out for ages.

I have an input textarea (div content editable field) into which I enter some text.

Then I have a "markup" button. Once this is pressed the text in the content editable is non-editable and each word in the text string is put into word tags. What I can do now is this. Click on any word of the text. It then adds an id to the span making the word (or words) red.

I also have an "edit" text button. If I press this the clean  tags are removed leaving only the ones with ids.

So now tge content editable field can be edited again showing some of the words that have been clicked (they are read). What I want to do is to delete the entire word if the user cursor is in front of the span, or tries to delete the "word" between the span container. Because if i delete "word" the  container is still active. So if I type something it will be red :(

Any way to force an entire span tag to be deleted if trying to delete its content?

Comment: provide some code or better a jsfiddle

Comment: .remove but I need to know when the "word" in between the span tags becomes empty?

Comment: Hello there <span id=1>dude</span>. So if "dude is deleted the span id=1 tag will be removed. It does this if I delete one more letter after hitting backspace and the span is empty. So I want to remove the spans around "dude" if dude text is deleted. Not having to press backspace an extra time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your last comms :

**HTML**

```
<span id=1>dude</span>
```

**JS**

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    if($(this).text()==="")$(this).remove();
    //if you want to extract from the tags
    //$(this).after($(this).text()).remove();
    //or more directly 
    //$(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/remove/
Select the dom element then call remove method.

Comment: Yes. I know how to remove the span tag with a specific id. But not how to check when a span tag is empty? Using a keydown=backspace would work but if the user selects the entire word and hits delete it does not fire.

Comment: .html() gets the inner html

Comment: Is therea way to force delete entire span if cursor is in front of a span tag and backspace is hit? Then i could make the spans nom-editable? Or convert them into images? That way the entire image-text would be removed?

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to create a non-editable tag inside a div contenteditable=true?